# Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring Security

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have trouble with handling AJAX request in Spring Security.

The spring security config is (Java config):

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/themes/**").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/offerings/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/users").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf();
    }
```

AJAX handle is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    ...
}
```

And AJAX JS code is

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/user/edit',
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

Everything will work fine if I disable `csrf` in Spring config like this `csrf().disable()`. So how to handle AJAX request when `csrf` is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Just add one more parameter in data when sending AJAX request is "_csrf" token key.

Comment: +1, Better to explain csrf token in ajax request....I found here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html